# Black & White Voronoi Cracks

Tags: texturing, node-editor

[image]Using Blender 2.81, 2 Voronoi Texture nodes, a Subtract node and a B/W ColoRamp, I draw cracks on a plane which is partly white and partly black.
However, the cracks are seen only on the white parts of the plane, but not on the black parts of the plane, no matter how I change the B/W colors of the ColoRamp node. Can you please let me know what should I do so as to see white cracks on black plane background and black cracks on white plane background? Thank you.

Comment: Cegaton, Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately I don’t fully understand it. Please note that I also have in my Shader Editor a principled shader which is connected to the Material Output shader. Whatever way I try to implement your solution, I don’t get the desired result. May I ask you to clarify your reply? Thank you again.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do. You plugged your cracks into the alpha input, which does not have an influence on the actual color of the shader but rather will make it transparent with a value of 0 and opaque with a value of 1. ie your cracks are actually holes in the material, hence why they always appear black. Note that you just have to set the voronoi type to "distance to edge" and plug it into the color ramp to have cracks

Comment: Cegaton, please excuse me. I attached a written explanation but only now, reading your reply, I realize that my text has not been sent along with the image. Indeed, I connect the cracks to the alpha input since I want them to be holes in the material with no influence on the color of the landscape. As you see in the image, I have a bumpy landscape which I want to cover with cracks. However, the cracks are black and therefore are seen only when they are on the bright parts of the landscape. I wish them to be white when they are on the dark parts of the landscape, so that they can be seen.